# Mdf file growing too large inserting binary data

Tags: c#, sql-server, memorystream, varbinary, responsestream

I'm taking jpegs and inserting them into a table as a byte array in a varbinary(MAX) data type field. However, the mdf file is growing three to four times larger in size the the total size of all of the files I'm inserting. I'm using a standard c# coding technique to take a webresponse and convert it into a memorystream:

```
byte[] result;
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

using (Stream responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int count = 0;
        do
        {
            count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);

        } while (count != 0);

        result = memoryStream.ToArray();

    }
}
```

And yet somehow 512mb of jpegs ends up growing the mdf over 2gb in size. Where I do the insert into the table I am defining the length on this field as well using result.length. Auto grow is set to 5%.

Comment: That is why files should be store like files in filesystem even if are jpges.

Answer (score 0):

A 512 MB jpeg should take just a bit over 512 mb in the database. The mdf itself may grow bigger, but that is subject to the database configured growth increment. [`sp_spaceused`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx) should show the used vs. free space.

But the way you're processing the file is actually quite bad, using a memory stream. Is never going to work. Read [Download and Upload images from SQL Server via ASP.Net MVC](http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/) for the correct way of streaming files from HTTP into the database. You must use [`UPDATE blob.write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177523.aspx) because of the app process memory size constraints and also because of database minimally logged operations requirements. The article linked explains in more details why and how to do it. you can use the same technique also to stream in a web response, w/o creating a full copy in memory.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, it's not 1 file, but hundreds of thousands. I'm downloading them via a webrequest and then inserting them into the DB, but as I said the mdf grows far too large and I don't understand why.

Comment: How big is each file, in average?

Comment: about 25k. Somehow they are getting "padded"

Comment: No padding can account for 4:1 ratio. Can you run `sp_spaceused` and `sp_spaceused <yourtable>` and post the results in your OP?

Comment: Unfortunately, I just shrank it after blowing away a bunch of records and am reloading it now. It will take a few hours!

Comment: How do you save the jpeg stream? You sure no conversion to nvarchar, no base64 encoding or anything similar occurs anywhere, right?